# Month wise tables from an attendance table using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that has attendance

```
Name      date          Remark
---------------------------
Jack     2014-10-08    P
Jill     2014-09-08    P
```

I want to generate multiple tables in HTML like

attendance of sept

```
Name     Remark
---------------
Jill     1
```

attendance of Oct

```
Name     total
---------------
Jack     1
```

How can i do it using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT count( `Remark` ) , `date` , group_concat( `Name` )
FROM `test`
GROUP BY month( `date` )
LIMIT 0 , 30

From above query You will get single row for month wise record and  name will display comm seperated .you can explode name with PHP and loop for it to generate HTML table

```
Resule Will Be shown Like this
```

Total Remark  Date           Name

```
1      2014-09-17   Jack

2       2014-10-31  Jill,Yogesh
```